# Need help dynamically updating a view ASP.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm having a hard time getting this to work, all I need to do is update a partial view with some data when a button is clicked. I can't seem to get it to work:

I have a view like this:

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyModel
<div class="container">
    <div class="myButton">Click Me to update data</div>
    @Html.Partial("_MyPartial")
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".myButton").click(function() {
            $.post("/Home/_MyPartial", { "param1" : "@DateTime.Now" }, function(result) {
                $(".myDivToUpdate").html(result);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ok, then in my home controller i have an ActionResult method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _MyPartial(DateTime param1)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    /* Update Model */
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

And in my partial view i have something i need to update dynamically:

```
<div class="myDivToUpdate">
    @Model.SomeInfo
</div>
```

Essentially that's the same way i have my stuff laid out. The problem is it never hits the controller when i hit the button in the first place. There may be other issues as I'm no jquery/javascript buff.

I'd appreciate any help on helping me get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hitting the controller action because you have marked the controller action with the attribute [HttpGet] which means it will only match on GET requests.  Your javascript is using a $.post